# Diverging Scattering Amplitudes and Transmission/Reflection Coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, singularities, dirac-delta-distributions, s-matrix-theory

I am currently studying scattering theory from Sakurai and Griffiths and I have noticed that for the 1D Dirac potential, the transmission and reflection coefficients diverge when the energy corresponds to the bound state energy. Is this only true for the Dirac potential or is it always true? If this is always true, what is the physical and/or mathematically reason for this?